# Twitter Sentiment Analysis using Tweepy

Tags: python, pandas, api, twitter, tweepy

```
 import sys,tweepy,csv,re
 from textblob import TextBlob
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

 consumerKey = 'xxxxx'
 consumerSecret = 'xxxxxxxx'
 accessToken = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
 accessTokenSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
 auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
 auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
 api = tweepy.API(auth)


 # input for term to be searched and how many tweets to search
   searchTerm = input("Enter Keyword/Tag to search about: ")
   NoOfTerms = int(input("Enter how many tweets to search: "))

 # searching for tweets
  tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchTerm, lang = "en").items(NoOfTerms)


  df = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets], columns =['tweets'])
```

*My code is working fine till this point as I'm able to stream the tweets and even get the text 
fields from the tweets. But I'm unable to create multiple columns for my pandas dataframe as shown 
in the code below.*

```
  df['len'] = np.array([len(tweet.text) for tweet in tweets])
  df['source'] = np.array([tweet.source for tweet in tweets])

  df
```

*This is the error I'm getting back.*

`ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

*Can someone please help me in fixing this issue? I also tried to use pd.Series inplace of np.array but even that is not working. I'm able to run the commands individually, but unable to add all the information to my dataframe.*

Comment: Since there's no data to reproduce the error, as first step of debug, I think you should check the length of `np.array([len(tweet.text) for tweet in tweets])` and `np.array([tweet.source for tweet in tweets])` and see which one is causing the problem. Then look into the array itself to see what's going on.

Comment: Since I'm myself passing the number of tweets to be extracted, I don't think there's a problem with that. The problem is arising when I'm trying to add these values to the same dataframe. Maybe I have to make sure the index stays same somehow. I don't know if that makes sense though.